# I want to dispay name of language as selected in option in paragraph but it is not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

i want to dispay language as selected in options but {{selectedlan.Language}} is not working

```
<div>
<select class="form-control col-md-3  col-6  mb1 id="" name="languages" ng-model="selectedlan"
ng-options="languages as languages.Language for languages in lan" autocomplete="off"                                                required>
</select>
<p>{{selectedlan.Language}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to add error your getting and print "selectedlan" and check is Language key is exits or not

Comment: The value you're looking for should just be `selectedlan` as that is what your `ng-model` shows

Comment: got the solution have to put @ before {{selectedlan.Language}}